# How does Dotty desugar polymorphic methods?

Tags: scala, dotty

Dotty reportedly desugars classes with type parameters to classes with type members, for example:

```
class C[T, U] { }
// <=>
class C {
  type C$T
  type C$U
}
```

How does Dotty desugar polymorphic methods like in the following example?

```
def m[T, U](x: T, u: U): T = x
// <=>
?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike polymorphic classes, polymorphic *methods* are not desugared. They fundamentally stay polymorphic.

Comment: By the way, do have any source/link on hand about this?

Comment: Maybe this qualifies: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/wiki/Type-System-Internals#representation-of-methods

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start at the bottom of page 13, section 5.2 of the most recent DOT paper [*The Essence of DOT* by Nada Amin, Samuel Grütter, Martin Odersky, Tiark Rompf, and Sandro Stucki](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/215280/files/paper_1.pdf). It shows the implementation of a simple covariant polymorphic `List[+A]` type in Scala. Of particular note is the polymorphic `cons[A]` method:

```
package scala.collection.immutable

trait List[+A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: A
  def tail: List[A]
}

object List {
  def cons[A](hd: A, tl: List[A]) = new List[A] {
    def isEmpty = false
    def head = hd
    def tail = tl
  }
}
```

And how it is encoded in DOT:

```
let scala_collection_immutable = ν(sci) {
  List = μ(self: {A; isEmpty: bool.Boolean; head: self.A; tail: sci.List∧{A <: self.A}})

cons: ∀(x: {A})∀(hd: x.A)∀(tl: sci.List∧{A <: x.A})sci.List∧{A <: x.A} =
  λ(x: {A})λ(hd: x.A)λ(tl: sci.List∧{A <: x.A})
    let result = ν(self) {
      A = x.A; isEmpty = bool.false; head = hd; tail = tl }
    in result
}: { μ(sci: {
  List <: μ(self: {A; head: self.A; tail: sci.List∧{A <: self.A}})

  cons: ∀(x: {A})∀(hd: x.A)∀(tl: sci.List∧{A <: x.A})sci.List∧{A <: x.A}
})}
in …
```

Which in turn should give you an intuition how it is encoded in Dotty.

Page 15 then shows you how the desugared DOT can be mapped back to Scala:

```
object scala_collection_immutable { sci => 
  trait List { self =>
    type A
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def head: self.A
    def tail: List{type A <: self.A}
  }

  def cons(x: {type A})(hd: x.A)(tl: sci.List{type A <: x.A}) 
    : sci.List{type A <: x.A} = new List{ self =>
    type A = x.A
    def isEmpty = false
    def head = hd
    def tail = tl
  }
}
```

As you can see, the encoding of a polymorphic method is more or less the same as a polymorphic trait: the type parameter becomes an abstract type member, in this case an abstract type member of a refinement type (aka structural type):

```
x : A
// becomes
x : {type A}
```

Comment: "Which in turn should give you an intuition how it is encoded in Dotty." Except it isn't encoded like that in Dotty. This answer is a very good answer to a different question: how are polymorphic methods encoded in *DOT* (not Dotty). DOT is a formalism used to study the foundations of Dotty, but Dotty is still quite a bit different from DOT as defined in the cited paper.